# Prove that $ \mathbf{Sim}_{\mathcal{A}}(P)=\mathbf{O}(2) $

Tags: analytic-geometry, symmetric-groups

For $ P(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{x} - 1 $ proof algebraically that $ \mathbf{Sim}_{\mathcal{A}}(P)=\mathbf{O}(2) $

Where, $ \mathbf{Sim}_{\mathcal{A}}(P):=\{g \in \mathcal{A}(2) \mid P \circ g=P\} $

---

**My attempt**

$ \subseteq$) Since $ \mathbf{Sim}_{\mathcal{A}}(P):=\{g \in \mathcal{A}(2) \mid P \circ g=P\} $, note that

$
 \begin{align*}
  P \circ g & = P \\
  (P \circ g)(\mathbf{x}) & = P(\mathbf{x}) \\
  (P(g(\mathbf{x})) & = \mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{x} - 1
 \end{align*}
$

Thus, observe that
$$ P(\mathbf{x}) \cdot P(\mathbf{x}) = (\mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{x} - 1) \cdot (\mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{x} - 1) $$
$$ P(g(\mathbf{x})) \cdot P(g(\mathbf{x})) = (\mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{x} - 1) \cdot (\mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{x} - 1)$$

It follows

$
 \begin{align*}
  P(\mathbf{x}) \cdot P(\mathbf{x}) & = P(g(\mathbf{x})) \cdot P(g(\mathbf{x}))\\
  %
  \mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{x} & = g(\mathbf{x}) \cdot g(\mathbf{x})
 \end{align*}
$

$$ \mathbf{Sim}_{\mathcal{A}}(P) \subseteq \mathbf{O}(2) $$

Not sure if that last step is correct (applied the inverse on both sides and distributed it)

$ \supseteq $) Suppose that $ g \in \mathbf{O}(2) $. Henceforth

$
\begin{align*}
 (P \circ g)(\mathbf{x}) \cdot (P \circ g)(\mathbf{y})
 & = P(g(\mathbf{x})) \cdot P(g(\mathbf{y}))\\
 & = P(g(\mathbf{x}) \cdot (g(\mathbf{y}))\\
 & = P(\mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{y})\\
 & = (\mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{x} -1) \cdot (\mathbf{y} \cdot \mathbf{y} -1)
\end{align*}
$

$$ \boxed{(P \circ g)(\mathbf{x}) \cdot (P \circ g)(\mathbf{y}) = P(\mathbf{x}) \cdot P(\mathbf{y})} $$

Since $ g \in \mathbf{O}(2) $, thus

$$ \mathbf{O}(2) \subseteq \mathbf{Sim}_{\mathcal{A}}(P) $$

---

The proof doesn't seem the be correct when applying the inverse in the first part and for the second part I have my doubts if the orthogonality of $g$ is being applied correctly. Moreover, in part two I'm using the fact that $ P(g(\mathbf{x})) \cdot P(g(\mathbf{y})) = P(g(\mathbf{x}) \cdot (g(\mathbf{y})) $ and I'd believe that I'd have to prove that first to use it (and maybe, it is not true!)